# Porque mis registros no estan siendo visualizados en mi vista?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Estoy trabajando con relaciones de muchos a muchos y tablas pivot con Laravel-7.
Tengo 3 tablas, products, presupuestos, y presupuesto_product. Y todo funciona perfecto, pero cuando quiero mostrar mis campos en la vista no aparece ningun registro es decir en mi data table no se esta mostrando nada. Esto es raro porque en mi base de datos los registros se estan guardando perfectamente.

Y este es mi controller de presupuesto:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Model\Presupuesto;
use App\Model\EstadoPresupuesto;
use App\Model\FormaDePago;
use App\Model\Customer;
use App\Model\Product;
use App\Model\PresupuestoProduct;
use Auth;
use Session;

public function view(){ 
    $file = Presupuesto::all();
    $file = PresupuestoProduct::all();
    return view('backend.presupuesto.view-presupuesto', compact('file'));
}

public function add(){
        $presupuesto['formasDePagos'] = FormaDePago::all();        
        $presupuesto['estadoPresupuestos'] = EstadoPresupuesto::all();
        $presupuesto['cuentas'] = Customer::all();
        $presupuesto_product['products'] = Product::all();
        $presupuesto_product['presupuestos'] = Presupuesto::all();
        return view('backend.presupuesto.add-presupuesto', $presupuesto, $presupuesto_product);
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        /*dd($request->all());*/
        $presupuesto = new Presupuesto();
        
        $presupuesto->cuenta_id = $request->cuenta_id;
        $presupuesto->formasDePago_id = $request->formasDePago_id;
        $presupuesto->estadosPresupuesto_id = $request->estadosPresupuesto_id;
        $presupuesto->idOwner = Auth::user()->id;
        $presupuesto->validez = $request->validez;
        $presupuesto->plazoEntrega = $request->plazoEntrega;
        $presupuesto->lugarDeEntrega = $request->lugarDeEntrega;
        $presupuesto->tipoCambio = $request->tipoCambio;
        $presupuesto->save();

        $presupuesto_product = new PresupuestoProduct();

        $presupuesto_product->product_id = $request->product_id;
        $presupuesto_product->quantity = $request->quantity;
        $presupuesto_product->total_price = $request->total_price;
        $presupuesto_product->presupuesto_id = $presupuesto->id;
        $presupuesto_product->save();


        Session::flash('success');
        return redirect()->route('presupuestos.view');
    }
```

Y esta es la manera en la que estoy intentando traer al nombre de mi producto para poder mostrarlo en la vista.

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-responsive" width="100%">
                        <thead class="thead">
                            <tr>
                                <th style="display: none">Codigo</th>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Fecha</th>
                                <th>Cuenta</th>
                                <th>Producto</th>
                                <th>Precio</th>
                                <th>Moneda</th>
                                <th>Forma de Pago</th>
                                <th>Estado</th>
                                <th>Validez</th>
                                <th>Plazo de Entrega</th>
                                <th>Lugar de Entrega</th>
                                <th>Owner</th>

                                
                                <th style="width: 12%">Accion</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>


 @foreach($file as $key => $presupuesto)
                            @if($presupuesto->status == 1)
                            <tr>
                                
                                <td style="display: none">{{ $key+1 }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $presupuesto->id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $presupuesto->created_at }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $presupuesto->cuenta->company}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $presupuesto_product->product->marca->brandName . " " . $presupuesto_product->product->modelo->modelName}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $presupuesto->product->list_price}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $presupuesto->product->sale_coin}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $presupuesto->FormaDePago->formaDePago}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $presupuesto->estadoPresupuesto->estado }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $presupuesto->validez }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $presupuesto->plazoEntrega }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $presupuesto->lugarDeEntrega }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $presupuesto->idOwner }}</td>
                                
                                
                                <td>


                                    <!--<a title="Download" id="download" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"
                                        href=""><i
                                            class="fa fa-download"></i></a>-->
                                    <a title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm text-white"
                                        style="background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #070525ce 1%, rgb(1, 0, 5)100%);"
                                        href="{{ route('presupuestos.edit', $presupuesto->id) }}"><i
                                            class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                    <a title="Delete" id="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                                        href="{{ route('presupuestos.delete', $presupuesto->id) }}"><i
                                            class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                    
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            @endif
                            @endforeach


    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

en la funcion `view` esta sobrescribiendo `$file`, con lo cual solo estas enviando `PresupuestoProduct::all();`

se puede pasar como un array hacia compact con distintos nombres.

```
public function view(){ 
    $presupuesto = Presupuesto::all();
    $presupuestoProduct = PresupuestoProduct::all();
    $data = [
        'presupuesto'  => $presupuesto,
        'presupuestoProduct'   => $presupuestoProduct
    ];
    return view('backend.presupuesto.view-presupuesto', compact('data'));
}
```

en la vista veo que cada presupuesto tiene un status donde preguntas si es igual a 1 `@if($presupuesto->status == 1)`, y es esta validación la que te permite mostrar o no los datos.